# Disambiguating the [solid] tag on SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-block-request

Currently SO contains <strike>57</strike> <strike>56</strike> 0 posts tagged [solid](/questions/tagged/solid). Out of these, most refer to the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) introduced by Uncle Bob Martin. The following two, however, seems to refer to solid bodies instead:

- [Starting point for learning CAD/CAE file formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024323/starting-point-for-learning-cad-cae-file-formats)
- [How to represent / Modify 3d solids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886536/how-to-represent-modify-3d-solids)

So I thought the tag should be split into [solid-principles](/questions/tagged/solid-principles) and [solid-bodies](/questions/tagged/solid-bodies), and the original [solid](/questions/tagged/solid) tag blacklisted.

Please post/comment if you have any issues or improvement suggestions. And of course, feel free to vote up or down to show your (dis)agreement :-)

Comment: Maybe `solid-oop` instead of `principles`? Don't know, just an idea

Comment: @Pekka, Not a bad idea, although IMHO it should be OOD rather than OOP. So how about `[solid-ood-principles]`?

Comment: @Péter that would be accurate but too long IMO. Would OOP as the "top category" not work here? (I can be totally wrong with this categorization, I'm not an expert in OOD theory.) The disambiguation should be as short and as clear as possible, like Wikipedia's  "Blue_(Colour)", "Blue_(Magazine)", and "Blue_(Movie)".

Comment: @Pekka, I don't really see a general consensus or pattern of following the Wikipedia convention in naming SO tags, but I may easily be ignorant - any feedback from the more knowledgeable would be appreciated.

Comment: +1 for the find; not sure what to do about it yet, though.

Comment: @Pekka, in the end I decided to implement my original idea; see my explanation in the body of the post. Thanks for your contribution though, it helped clarifying my thoughts :-)

Comment: You should post the update as an answer, though blacklisting [solid] might still be needed.

Comment: @Peter yeah! Looks perfectly fine, good job.

Comment: @Moderators, shall I leave the answer unaccepted until the blacklisting is done? What is the preferred way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 2):

After a few days' of letting my thoughts settle, I decided to implement my original idea of splitting the tag into [solid-principles](/questions/tagged/solid-principles) and [solid-bodies](/questions/tagged/solid-bodies). Although Pekka suggested an alternative, in the end I felt that [solid-principles](/questions/tagged/solid-principles) is the simplest and most expressive tag in this case. (The term "SOLID principles" is clearly related to OO, and AFAIK there are no known principles marked with the same acronym but relating to other programming paradigms, so I felt no need for classification.)

I have done the retagging today, in the hope that this helps making SO a tad cleaner, nicer and less ambiguous place :-)